# Python3 apache avro 1.8.2 not providing aliases

Tags: python-3.x, avro, avro-tools

I have the following python3 avro program:

```
import avro.schema
import json
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter


write_schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps({
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
         {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
         {"name": "favorite_number", "type": ["int", "null"]},
         {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
     ]
}))

writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), write_schema)
writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"})
writer.close()

read_schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps({
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "first_name", "type": "string", "default": "", "aliases": ["name"]},
        {"name": "favorite_number", "type": ["int", "null"]},
        {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
    ]
}))

reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader(write_schema, read_schema))
new_schema = reader.get_meta("avro.schema")
users = []
for user in reader:
    users.append(user)
reader.close()
```

The contents of `users` follows:

```
[{'favorite_color': None, 'favorite_number': 256, 'first_name': ''},
 {'favorite_color': 'red', 'favorite_number': 7, 'first_name': ''}]
```

I would have thought that it would have 'Ben' and 'Alyssa' in the `first_name` field.  How do aliases in this library work?  Is this following the specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I have now discovered that the python version of the standard avro package doesn't implement aliasing (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1303).  As this has been around since 2013/2014, I don't expect a standard fix anytime soon.  More promising is the fastavro project which is working on a fix.

Answer (score 1):

This does work using `fastavro`. Here's the same snippet using that library:

```
from io import BytesIO
from fastavro import reader, writer

write_schema = {
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
         {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
         {"name": "favorite_number", "type": ["int", "null"]},
         {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
     ]
}

records = [
    {"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256},
    {"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"}
]

bio = BytesIO()
writer(bio, write_schema, records)

bio.seek(0)

read_schema = {
    "namespace": "example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "first_name", "type": "string", "default": "", "aliases": ["name"]},
        {"name": "favorite_number", "type": ["int", "null"]},
        {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
    ]
}

for record in reader(bio, read_schema):
    print(record)
```

And the output:

```
{'first_name': 'Alyssa', 'favorite_number': 256, 'favorite_color': None}
{'first_name': 'Ben', 'favorite_number': 7, 'favorite_color': 'red'}
```